# Interrupted For Loop C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, break

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text, findstring, replacestring;
    int i = -1;
    cout << "Text eingeben: ";
    getline( cin, text ); 
    cout << "findstring: ";
    cin >> findstring; 
    cout << "replacestring: "; 
    cin >> replacestring;
    if( text.find( findstring, 0 ) == -1 ) {
        cout << "Fehler: findString ist nicht vorhanden" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i; i>text.length();++i) {
        i =    text.find( findstring, i+1 );

            cout << "String " << findstring << " gefunden an Pos: " << i << endl;
            text.replace( i, findstring.length(), replacestring );

    }
    cout << "Ergebnis: " << text << endl;
    cout << text.length();
    return 0;
}
```

which searches for a string inside another string and gives back its position plus replaces it with another one. Now my question is, why does this not work when the target string is included many times in the original one?  I tried using a do...while loop and it was working perfectly.  I want to know how to do this with a for loop.

Comment: `i > text.length()` will never be true, since you initialize `i` to `-1`.

Comment: Is there a missing `if` before `i = text.find`?

Comment: You probably just need to change that `>` to `<` and add the missing `if`.

Comment: You can also get into an infinite loop of `replacestring` contains `findstring`, e.g. if you replace `bar` with `foobar`. The first replacement changes it to `foobar`, then it changes that to `foofoobar`, then `foofoofoobar`, and so on forever.

Comment: *why does this not work when the "searched for" string is included many times in the original one* -- Now is a good time to familiarize yourself with using the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.  All of the comments given to you could have been discovered by using the debugger.

Comment: there's no missing `if`because `text.find()`returns a `int` and i don't see how changing to `>`will make right can you elaborate `?

Comment: @Barmar i changed the code but still nothing

Comment: @SalemSfaxi - [I downvoted because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).  You could have done the simplest of things by outputting the value of variables, loop indices, etc, to see where things go wrong.  You're being downvoted more than likely due to the lack of debugging effort.

Comment: @SalemSfaxi `for(i; i > text.length(); ++i)` executes when `i > text.length()` is true. Since `-1 > text.length()` is not true (length is always at least 0), the loop doesn't execute.

Comment: When you're counting up, a `for` loop almost always uses `<` not `>`. Remember that the condition is for when to keep repeating, not when to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. The error is caused by comparing `i` with `text.length()`. `i` is an int with value of `-1`, while `text.length()` is an `unsigned type`, thus `-1 is always > text.length()`. That is why your `for loop` runs only once (when `i` is still `-1`).

Here is a possible way to fix (runs well on my machine):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text, findstring, replacestring;
    int i = -1;

    cout << "Text eingeben: ";
    getline(cin, text);
    cout << "findstring: ";
    cin >> findstring;
    cout << "replacestring: ";
    cin >> replacestring;

    if( text.find( findstring, 0 ) == -1 ) {
        cout << "Fehler: findString ist nicht vorhanden" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << endl;

    do {
        i = text.find(findstring, i + 1);
        if (i == -1) {
            cout << "No more result found" << endl;
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "String " << findstring << " gefunden an Pos: " << i << endl;
            text.replace(i, findstring.length(), replacestring);
        }

    } while (true);
    cout << "Ergebnis: " << text << endl;
    cout << text.length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```